# Display javascript content via php

Tags: javascript, php, html

hello im trying to display javascript content in php, but i get only javascript raw code i need get actually javascript content for example in html when i put :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.cpagrip.com/script_include.php?id=25002&tracking_id="></script>
```

then its normal but when im trying to display content in paticular place like this:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('https://www.cpagrip.com/script_include.php?id=25002&tracking_id=');
echo $content;
?>
```

it showing me raw code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `<script>` tag:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('https://www.cpagrip.com/script_include.php?id=25002&tracking_id=');
echo '<script type="text/javascript">' . $content . '</script>';
?>
```